# Problema con QCMediaPlayer could not be located, como lo resuelvo?

Tags: android-studio, youtube, uri

Estoy intentado reproducir un video que esta en youtube "oculto" pero aparece este error:

> `E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer could not be located....
>   E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
>   E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer could not be located....
>   E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
>   W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open requested URI.
>   D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x7f6fd13000 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x7f6fc18400
>   I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1688043 time:1414328
>   E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
>   E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
>   D/VideoView: Error: 1,-2147483648`

Y este es mi código:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_curso1);

        video1 = findViewById(R.id.v1);
        pd=new ProgressDialog(Curso1.this);
        ur1= findViewById(R.id.t1);
        pd.setMessage("Cargando por favor espere");
        pd.show();
        Uri uri= Uri.parse(video1_url);
        video1.setVideoURI(uri);
        video1.start();
        video1.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Gracias

Comment: El error parece indicar que el dispositivo movil no tiene la capacidad de reproducir este tipo de vídeo.

Comment: @Bryant Ayala tienes la posibilidad de compartir el url del video, el problema generalmente es lo que indica Alvaro y la razón son los codecs usados para crear el video.

Comment: @AlvaroC. https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/live4train-e8ee1.appspot.com/o/700_F_100754967_oGdhgbHEXimChwilYiWeETeyioEJHzcv.mp4?alt=media&token=fe160f99-671d-4b8e-bf25-ffc5c8b41c3a gracias

Comment: @Jorgesys https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/live4train-e8ee1.appspot.com/o/700_F_100754967_oGdhgbHEXimChwilYiWeETeyioEJHzcv.mp4?alt=media&token=fe160f99-671d-4b8e-bf25-ffc5c8b41c3a gracias